# ZF2 dynamic hostname route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have to develop some widget function for my application. The way you can inject it on your website should look something like that:

```
<script src="http://connect.myapp.com/myjs.js"></script>
<app:widget param1="param"></app:widget>
```

Now I wanna handle that on the subdomain **connect.myapp.com**. First I thought of a hostname route with child routes, but then I had the problem with my environments. If I configure zf2 with a hostname route connect.myapp.com, it's very static and I can't use a hostname like connect.myapp.local in my development environment.

So what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$this->basePath()` or using

`echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath('myjs.js'))`

which will produce something similar to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/myjs.js"></script>`

Comment: It is an external widget, which can be injected to any website. So the part described above is completly static. It's like a facebook like button or something similar.

Comment: You can still try $this->basePath()/my.js or $this->serverUrl()

`echo $this->serverUrl(); 
// output: http://example.com`